# How to handle DataIntegrityViolationException in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-mvc

I need to show custom messages in my Spring 3.0 application. I have a database with Hibernate and there are several constraints. I have doubts in how `DataIntegrityViolationException` should be handled in a good way. I wonder if there is a way to map the exception with a message set in a properties file, as it is possible in Constraints validation. Could I handle it automatically in any way or I have to catch this exception in each controller?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem with showing user-friendly messages in the case of constraint violation is that the constraint name is lost when Hibernate's `ConstraintViolationException` is being translated into Spring's `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

However, you can customize this translation logic. If you use `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to access Hibernate, you can supply it with a custom `SQLExceptionTranslator` (see `LocalSessionFactoryBean.jdbcExceptionTranslator`). This exception translator can translate a `ConstraintViolationException` into your own exception class, preserving the constraint name.

Comment: Do you have a example of this?

Answer (score 18):

I treat `DataIntegrityViolationException` in [`ExceptionInfoHandler`](https://github.com/gkislin/topjava/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/javawebinar/topjava/web/ExceptionInfoHandler.java), finding DB constraints occurrences in root cause message and convert it into i18n message via `constraintCodeMap`:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionInfoHandler {

  @Autowired
  private final MessageSourceAccessor messageSourceAccessor;

  private static Map<String, String> CONSTRAINS_I18N_MAP = Map.of(
      "users_unique_email_idx", EXCEPTION_DUPLICATE_EMAIL,
      "meals_unique_user_datetime_idx", EXCEPTION_DUPLICATE_DATETIME);

  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)  // 409
  @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
  public ErrorInfo conflict(HttpServletRequest req, DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    String rootMsg = ValidationUtil.getRootCause(e).getMessage();
    if (rootMsg != null) {
        String lowerCaseMsg = rootMsg.toLowerCase();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : CONSTRAINS_I18N_MAP.entrySet()) {
            if (lowerCaseMsg.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                return logAndGetErrorInfo(req, e, VALIDATION_ERROR, messageSourceAccessor.getMessage(entry.getValue()));
            }
        }
    }
    return logAndGetErrorInfo(req, e, DATA_ERROR);
  }

  //  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65442410/548473
  @NonNull
  private static Throwable getRootCause(@NonNull Throwable t) {
    Throwable rootCause = NestedExceptionUtils.getRootCause(t);
    return rootCause != null ? rootCause : t;
  }
  ...
}
```

Can be simulated in my [Java Enterprise training application](http://topjava.herokuapp.com) by adding/editing user with duplicate mail or meal with duplicate dateTime.

**UPDATE**:

Other solution: use [Controller Based Exception Handling](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#controller-based-exception-handling):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ajax/admin/users")
public class AdminAjaxController {

    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorInfo> duplicateEmailException(HttpServletRequest req, DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        return exceptionInfoHandler.getErrorInfoResponseEntity(req, e, EXCEPTION_DUPLICATE_EMAIL, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
```

Comment: Did you have a different config to get that constraint friendly? My constraint are something like this `UK_6DOTKOTT2KJSP8VW4D0M25FB7_INDEX_4`

Comment: There are several way to create readable constraints: 1. In initial SQL script. 
2.  DB auto generation with `uniqueConstraints` parameter in `@Table` annotation, e.g.
`@Table(name = "meals", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "date_time"}, name = "meals_unique_user_datetime_idx")})`

Answer (score 4):

Spring 3 provides two ways of handling this - `HandlerExceptionResolver` in your beans.xml, or `@ExceptionHandler` in your controller. They both do the same thing - they turn the exception into a view to render.

Both are documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers).

Answer (score 0):

**1. In your request body class check for not null or not empty like this**

```
public class CustomerRegisterRequestDto {
    @NotEmpty(message = "first name is empty")
    @NotNull(message = Constants.EntityValidators.FIRST_NAME_NULL)
    private String first_name;
    //other fields
    //getters and setters
}
```

**2. Then in your service check for this**

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<CustomerRegisterRequestDto>> violations = validator.validate(userDto);
    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
        //something is wrong in request parameters
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ConstraintViolation<CustomerRegisterRequestDto> violation : violations) {
            details.add(violation.getMessage());
        }
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse(Constants.ErrorResponse.REQUEST_PARAM_ERROR, details);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

**3. [Here](https://github.com/lokeshgupta1981/SpringExamples/blob/db5ca189f93de972d592f3864bd9e8fff8a19149/unit-testing/src/main/java/com/howtodoinjava/rest/exception/ErrorResponse.java) is your ErrorResponse class**