# Best practice propagating Unique Violation Exceptions to UI

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, jpa, constraints

We are working on Java web project based on JPA 2, Hibernate, Spring 3 and JSF 2 running in Tomcat 7. We are using Oracle 11g as database.

We are currently holding a debate on approaches to populate database constraint violations as user-friendly messages to the UI. More or less we see two ways, both are not really satisfying. Could somebody give some advise?

**Approach 1 - Validate programmatically and throw specific exception**

In CountryService.java each Unique constraint will be validated and a corresponding exception is thrown. The exceptions are handled individually in a backing bean.

*Advantage*: Easy to understand and maintain. Specific User messages possible.

*Disadvantage*: A lot of code just for having nice messages. Basically all DB Constraints are written again in the application. A lot of queries - unnecessary db load.

```java
@Service("countryService")
public class CountryServiceImpl implements CountryService {

    @Inject
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Override
    public Country saveCountry(Country country) throws NameUniqueViolationException,  IsoCodeUniqueViolationException, UrlUniqueViolationException {
        if (!isUniqueNameInDatabase(country)) {
            throw new NameUniqueViolationException();
        }
        if (!isUniqueUrl(country)) {
            throw new UrlUniqueViolationException();
        }
        if (!isUniqueIsoCodeInDatabase(country)) {
            throw new IsoCodeUniqueViolationException();
        }
        return countryRepository.save(country);
    }
}
```

In the View's Backing Bean you handle the exceptions:

```java
@Component
@Scope(value = "view")
public class CountryBean {

    private Country country;

    @Inject
    private CountryService countryService;

    public void saveCountryAction() {
        try {
            countryService.saveCountry(country);
        } catch (NameUniqueViolationException e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("name", new FacesMessage("A country with the same name already exists."));
        } catch (IsoCodeUniqueViolationException e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("isocode", new FacesMessage("A country with the same isocode already exists."));
        } catch (UrlUniqueViolationException e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("url", new FacesMessage("A country with the same url already exists."));
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
             // update: in case of concurrent modfications. should not happen often
             FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("The country could not be saved."));
        }
    }
}
```

**Approach 2 - Let the database detect constraint violations**

*Advantage*: No boiler plate code. No unnecessary queries to db. No duplication of data constraint logic.

*Disadvantage*: Dependencies to constraint names in DB, so generation of Schema through hibernate not possible. Mechanism needed to bind messages to input components (e.g. for highlighting).

```java
public class DataIntegrityViolationExceptionsAdvice {
    public void afterThrowing(DataIntegrityViolationException ex) throws DataIntegrityViolationException {

        // extract the affected database constraint name:
        String constraintName = null;
        if ((ex.getCause() != null) && (ex.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException)) {
            constraintName = ((ConstraintViolationException) ex.getCause()).getConstraintName();
        }

        // create a detailed message from the constraint name if possible
        String message = ConstraintMsgKeyMappingResolver.map(constraintName);
        if (message != null) {
            throw new DetailedConstraintViolationException(message, ex);
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are still relying on the database to detect constraint violations in Approach 1, in the event that a user saves a duplicate country after the unique check but before the save of a second user.

Comment: we are aware of the concurrent issue here. it is not mandatory for our use cases. it is enough, if in 90% of the cases the message is specific. if in exceptional cases, a more generic message is triggered by db doesn't matter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Approach 1 will not work in a concurrent scenario! -- There is always a change that somebody else insert a new database record after you checked but before you added your database record. (except you use isolation level serializable, but this is highly unlikely)

So you have to handle the DB constraint violation exceptions. But I recommend to catch the database exception that indicates the unique violation and throw a more meaning full like you suggested in Approach 1.

Comment: as i wrote to ken, the concurrent issue doesn't matter. in those exceptional cases a more generic message (violation triggered by db will be shown). updated approach 1.

Comment: Anyway, this will not change my suggested approach.

Comment: What I don't like about it, is that normally during development hibernate will generate the constraint names. With approach 2 we need to maintain the names seprately through additional scripts.

Comment: The Unique Constraint has a name Attribute! `@javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint(name, columnName)`

Comment: as much as i know hibernate ignores the name attribute on UniqueConstraint. it won't be used when generating the schema.

Comment: ...just to confirm the previous statement, I used `@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "users_unique_email", columnNames = {"email"})})` with my `User` entity, and then tried to fetch it via `getConstraintName()` while persisting user with duplicate email. It heavily depends on underlying RDBMS, because I get different constraints names for different databases (particularly in case of Postgres - I get `null` and have to parse `sqlException` to figure out what field was exactly duplicated, which can be a pain if I decide to add more than one unique constraint).

Answer (score 17):

This may also be an option, and might be less costly because you only do checks for a detailed exception if you can't save outright:

```
try {
    return countryRepository.save(country);
}
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
    if (!isUniqueNameInDatabase(country)) {
        throw new NameUniqueViolationException();
    }
    if (!isUniqueUrl(country)) {
        throw new UrlUniqueViolationException();
    }
    if (!isUniqueIsoCodeInDatabase(country)) {
        throw new IsoCodeUniqueViolationException();
    }
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Thx, defintely better than approach 1! Only drawback i see is, that you manually need to flush after calling `countryRepository.save(country)`.

Comment: Nice, but keep in mind that you will not be able to catch the exception if save is inside a method annotated with @Transactional

Answer (score 1):

To avoid boilerplate I treat `DataIntegrityViolationException` in `ExceptionInfoHandler`, finding DB constraints occurrences in root cause message and convert it into i18n message via map. See code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42422568/548473