# Spring constraint error happens only on commit

Tags: spring, transactions

I am using spring transactional annotation at service layer.
Whenever unique constraint exception is thrown , the actual exception occurs only during transaction commit not at the time when we do the entity.save

Because of this I am not able to catch the exception and throw my custom exception for unique constraint ( I don't want to use the spring exception translator feature since I need additional data to be set in the exception )

Let me know if anybody has faced this issue

Thanks

Comment: _Let me know if anybody has faced this issue_ I have faced this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a normal behavior to me.
It's only when the transaction is ran against the database that the unique constraint can be detected. When you do enity.save(), the ORM you are using (hibernate ?) could only detect unique constraint if it has the other object with same unique constraint in memory.

Following post [Best practise propagating Unique Violation Exceptions to UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842672/best-practise-propagating-unique-violation-exceptions-to-ui) seems quite related to your question.

Hope this helps