# How can we give different customs messages for the same exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, jakarta-ee

Since handling this scenario for the first time, asking to know which is best approach.

Here for all the  `DataIntegrityViolationException`, sending the same error message

```
@Override
public boolean saveParam(ParamDto dto) throws ParamException 
{
    try 
    {
        return super.save(dto);
    }
    catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e)
    {
        throw new ParamException(ParamException.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, messageSource.getMessage(CodeEnum.DUPLICATE_APP.getValue(), new Object[] { dto.getParamKey() }, Locale.ENGLISH));
    } 
    catch (GenericException ge) 
    {
        throw new ParamException(ge, ge.getRootCauseMessage());
    }
}
```

How can we give different customs messages for the same exception. Do we need to check the message string ?

Here having 2 different kind of exception under `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

> 1. "ERROR: value too long for type character(1)" (id=172) ""
> 2. "ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_param_key"\n  Detail: Key (param_key)=(Test1) already exists."

Comment: You can use JdbcExceptionTranslator . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109476/how-to-handle-dataintegrityviolationexception-in-spring

Answer (score 1):

As you're already doing once you have caught the `DataIntegrityViolationException` exception use [getMostSpecificCause](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException.html#getMostSpecificCause()) method to get the actual cause of the exception.

Then you can check to see if the exception is of specific type with `instanceof` keyword and customize your message accordingly. For example, MySQL JDBC driver throws `MysqlDataTruncation`, `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` etc. for different types of errors. Check documentation to see the different types of exceptions thrown by your database driver.

Also you can check the exception message and compare it with a pre-defined message but this is a bit tricky and error-prone.