# How to handle the SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, sqlexception

I'm working at a RestController and I try to handle the SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException using try-catch blocks but I don't know why the catch block is never executed.

This is the RestController:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class UserJPAResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserJpaRepository userJpaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @GetMapping("/allusers")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userJpaRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/allusers")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword())); 

        User createdUser = new User();

        try {    
            createdUser = save(user);


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if(e instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
                if(e.getSQLState().equals("23000")) {
                    if(e.getMessage().contains("Duplicate")) {
                        if (e.getMessage().contains("username")) {
                            System.out.println("Duplicate username"); 
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Duplicate email"); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                .path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(createdUser.getId()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();

    }

    public User save(User user) throws SQLException {
        User newUser = userJpaRepository.save(user);
        return newUser;
    }
}
```

If I try to add an user with an username or email that is already in the database I get the SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException error in the console:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'dgs' for key 'username'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:974) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1113) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1381) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3072) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3663) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:800) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:489) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.dgs.restful.webservices.goaltrackerservice.user.UserJPAResource.save(UserJPAResource.java:72) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.dgs.restful.webservices.goaltrackerservice.user.UserJPAResource.createUser(UserJPAResource.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:142) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58748439/8874958

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you are using spring-data JPA repository to save entity you should catch `DataIntegrityViolationException` instead of `SQLException`

Comment: Doesn't DataAccessException catch that?

Comment: This doesn't work properly. Its very surprising that something as basic as this is causing issues. This should work out of the box. When I try this there is a UnexpectedRollback exception.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue rn, what @Kapil suggested didn't work for me, When digging in the exception logs I've found that the exception is thrown after the method finishes which is weird, I think there is some spring-boot mechanism underlining that makes it the way it is

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32925918)