# How to write test to check SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

In my Spring boot app  I want to write a test to assert [SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.html)

```
    @Test
    public void deleteCar_whenIntegrityConstraintViolationException()
    {
        doThrow( new SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException() ).when( carRepository ).deleteCar( anyInt() );
        CustomResponse response = carService.deleteCar( 5 );
        Assert.assertEquals( "unsuccessful", response.getStatus() );
    }
```

I have set `CustomResonse` to be unsuccessful when Exception occurred.

but the problem is Mockito [don't allow me to test arbitrary exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762047/throw-checked-exceptions-from-mocks-with-mockito) as mentioned in this stack answer

> If you really want to do this, then have Mockito throw a new
> RuntimeException() or even better throw a new
> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException() since the API specifies that that is
> the only valid Exception to be thrown.

is there any other way to test this `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` ?.

Answer (score 0):

in case u use JUnit4 add new line in test method that using when()

```
when(carRepository.deleteCar(5)).thenThrow(SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class);
```

Comment: same error org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Comment: you cannot throw a checked exception from a method that doesnt declare it. Probably you should throw a DataAccessException (which is aRuntimeException from spring). take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54035808/how-to-handle-the-sqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception-in-spring-boot