# How can I loop through Exception getCause() to find root cause with detail message

Tags: java, exception, plsql

I am trying to call `saveOrUpdate()` in hibernate to save data. Since columns have unique index, so its throws `ConstraintViolationException` when I look through via Eclipse debugger.

Since root cause could be different for different exception while inserting data to table.
I wanted to know, how can I loop / traverse through `getCause()` to check what is the root cause of exception and its message.

Update:
Thanks everyone for your kind response, thing is I want output like in below image:
[image]
I need to access  **detailMessage** field.
(I am really sorry If could not make my question more clear.)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you call the "root cause" exactly? The DB-specific exception?

Comment: @fge, Yes its DB specific exception and question is updated.

Comment: Maybe `.getSQLException().getMessage()` then?

Comment: @fge, thing is I do not know what kind of exception will be thrown, hence I used parent class `Exception` to catch any possible exception. so `.getSQLException()...` wont work I guess.

Comment: Well, catch JDBCException then, or HibernateException. You should never catch `Exception` to begin with.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65442410/548473 in case you have Spring dependency

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The Apache [ExceptionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html) provide the following method:

```
Throwable getRootCause(Throwable throwable)
```

as well as

```
String getRootCauseMessage(Throwable th)
```

Comment: You can find something similar in Guava's [Throwables](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html): `getRootCause(Throwable)` and `getStackTraceAsString(Throwable)`

Comment: However Guava has an [issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1173) regarding db style exception, thus creating infinite loops.

Comment: Yes but this requires using Guava or Apache Commons, if your project is small enough it doesn't make sense, have a look at my anwser bellow I provide a 3 line util function.

Comment: Mehdi, your solution doesn't seem to handle possible infinite loops.

Comment: Unfortunately, Apache's solution will return the same exception if it is equal to the root cause. Sometimes that's not the intend. I would say to use Legna's.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65442410/548473 in case you have Spring dependency (`NestedExceptionUtils.getRootCause`)

Answer (score 93):

I normally use the implementation below instead of Apache's one.

Besides its complexity, Apache's implementation returns null when no cause is found, which force me to perform an additional check for null.

Normally when looking for an exception's root/cause I already have a non-null exception to start with, which is for all intended proposes is the cause of the failure at hand, if a deeper cause can't be found.

```
Throwable getCause(Throwable e) {
    Throwable cause = null; 
    Throwable result = e;

    while(null != (cause = result.getCause())  && (result != cause) ) {
        result = cause;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Indeed its helpful ! :) Thanks !

Comment: I believe such answers should be prefered by the questioner and the community as opposed to the answers with only a tool or lib recommendation.

Comment: The implementation I provided above is guards you from cyclically chained exceptions  of just one step in depth, meaning when the exception chains to itself e = e.getCause() (the most common and only situation I have met). 

Nevertheless apache's implementation will really guard your code from cyclic exception chains of any depth e = e.getCause().getCause()... etc .. .getCause();

Comment: in which cases (result != cause) will help?

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh '(result != cause)' will help every single time 'result' has a non null cause.

the condition/expression on the while statement evaluates in the following order:
1.- assign cause = result.getCause()
2.- evaluates the result of the assignment above for null. null != cause
3.- if cause == null the whole expression evaluates to false, otherwise it proceeds to
4.- evaluate (result != cause) and that's your result

Comment: No additional libraries or frameworks, simple and doable logic, thanks for this answer!

Comment: -1: *Apache's implementation returns null when no cause is found, which force me to perform an additional check for null.*: er? `ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(new Exception())` returns the input Exception, so I think the whole benefit argument provided in the answer is misguided.  In fact, the implementation in the answer produces the exact same result as `ExceptionUtils.getRootCause()`, but unlike Apache's, has only marginal handling for cyclic causes so can go into an infinite loop.

Comment: would there be any concern with using such code in production?

Answer (score 28):

Using java 8 Stream API, this can be achieved by:

```
Optional<Throwable> rootCause = Stream.iterate(exception, Throwable::getCause)
                                      .filter(element -> element.getCause() == null)
                                      .findFirst();
```

Note that this code is not immune to exception cause loops and therefore should be avoided in production.

Comment: I like this code, but failed to understand why it should be avoided in production, is there an example?

Comment: @A.S.Ranjan I think you should post a question of its own on SO and ask what a exeption cause loop is and why this can be dangerous in production to encounter.

Answer (score 10):

Are you asking for something like this?

```
Throwable cause = originalException;
while(cause.getCause() != null && cause.getCause() != cause) {
    cause = cause.getCause();
}
```

or am I missing something?

Comment: Exception is basically of DB type exceptions. so above while loop goes in indefinite loop.

Comment: It can be N causes deep....  cause.getCause().getCause().getCause().. hence the need for something like  Apache ExceptionUtils.getRootCause()

Answer (score 8):

[Guava's `Throwables`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html) provides the following methods:

```
Throwable getRootCause(Throwable throwable)
```

as well as

```
String getStackTraceAsString(Throwable throwable)
```

Answer (score 4):

In [APACHE](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html); the implementation is like below.

The highlight is **list.contains(throwable) == false**

```
public static Throwable getRootCause(final Throwable throwable) {
    final List<Throwable> list = getThrowableList(throwable);
    return list.size() < 2 ? null : (Throwable)list.get(list.size() - 1);
}

public static List<Throwable> getThrowableList(Throwable throwable) {
    final List<Throwable> list = new ArrayList<Throwable>();
    while (throwable != null && list.contains(throwable) == false) {
        list.add(throwable);
        throwable = ExceptionUtils.getCause(throwable);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
    while (ex.getCause() != null)
        ex = ex.getCause();
    System.out.println("Root cause is " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Were you expecting something more complicated?

Comment: actually I am getting database regarding exception, so in that case above logic is not working. anyway thanks for your response. :)

Comment: This is not immune to loops - the case where an exception cause points to exception itself.

Comment: @agpt why the above logic does not work with the database in relation to exclusion?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you can put this function in a kind of Util class:

```
public static Throwable getRootException(Throwable exception){
 Throwable rootException=exception;
 while(rootException.getCause()!=null){
  rootException = rootException.getCause();
 }
 return rootException;
}
```

Example of usage :

```
catch(MyException e){
  System.out.println(getRootException(e).getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Source : [How to get the root exception of any exception](https://tutoref.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Recursively:

```
public static Throwable getRootCause(Throwable e) {
    if (e.getCause() == null) return e;
    return getRootCause(e.getCause());
}
```

Comment: Might want to replace `if (e.getCause() == null)` with `if (e == null)` else you'll lose one level information.