# Excluding certain exceptions from being reported to Sentry

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, kotlin, sentry

A spring-boot based web service is using Sentry as described in the [docs](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/spring/). It works fine, but some exceptions should not be sent to Sentry, e.g. an exception thrown in order to return HTTP status `410` on certain requests:

```
// Kotlin code, but in Java it would be similar.
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.GONE)
class GoneException(msg: String) : RuntimeException(msg) {
}
```

How can I tell my `sentryExceptionResolver` to skip these exceptions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python it's simple you just add the below code in config file to ignore multiple exceptions

```
ignore_exceptions = [
    'Http404',
    'Http401'
    'django.exceptions.http.Http404',
    'django.exceptions.*',
    ValueError,
]
```

But in Java I cant find similar tags in `sentry.properties`, try yourself maybe you will find it.

```
##Just give it a try, I didnt test    
ignore.exceptions:
        HTTP 401
```

**OR** you can add `HandlerExceptionResolver` in you Configuration class and override the `resolveException()` method and ignore exceptions manually:

```
@Configuration
public class FactoryBeanAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver sentryExceptionResolver() {
        return new SentryExceptionResolver() {
            @Override
            public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response,
                    Object handler,
                    Exception ex) {
                Throwable rootCause = ex;

                while (rootCause .getCause() != null && rootCause.getCause() != rootCause) {
                    rootCause = rootCause.getCause();
                }

                if (!rootCause.getMessage().contains("HTTP 401")) {
                    super.resolveException(request, response, handler, ex);
                }
                return null;
            }   

        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer sentryServletContextInitializer() {
        return new SentryServletContextInitializer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I too did not find something like the `ignore_exception`. So I [translated your code to Kotlin](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/932be3b979751287c4cb007af1cb17ad) and it works.

Comment: Can someone please elaborate on `while (rootCause .getCause() != null && rootCause.getCause() != rootCause) {` part? It's clear that it drills down to find the root cause of an exception ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747175/how-can-i-loop-through-exception-getcause-to-find-root-cause-with-detail-messa)), but since OP is targeting "top" level exception I'm not sure that part is necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on surrounding frameworks, you may not know (or want to know) which exception Sentry eventually sees, so drilling down definitely makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can set;

```
ignored-exceptions-for-type=java.lang.RuntimeException,java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/configuration/