# SentryIO: prevent sentry from sending unhandled exceptions

Tags: java, sentry

I'm using SentryIO in my Java projects. Sentry sends currently all exceptions (+ unhandled), but I only want to receive exceptions (handled exceptions) from my resource. I'm not sure, how to exclude external resources and I haven't found any docs for this yet.

Comment: What do you mean by your resource and external resource? Do you use Spring/Spring Boot integrations?

Comment: duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/a/75204496/2165146