# Spring Boot: Handle Raised Exception from Database Trigger

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement to prevent the update action for ceratin columns in the table and display the message. I am using the liquibase to manage the database schema. To achieve this I used the Trigger Functions and Triggers which works fine.

**Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_BU_CATEGORY() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF NEW.created_by <> OLD.created_by THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Not allowed to update the value of created_by';
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;
```

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_BU_CATEGORY
BEFORE UPDATE ON category FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE FN_BU_CATEGORY();
```

---

I am managing the exception handling using `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` with `PSQLException.class, GenericJDBCException.class, JpaSystemException.class` and I was able to handle the exception. To verify the functionality, when I make an API hit to update the values of restricted columns, trigger raised the exception and I can see the following in the console.

**handleTriggerException**

```
@ExceptionHandler({PSQLException.class, GenericJDBCException.class, JpaSystemException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleTriggerException(Exception ex, NativeWebRequest request) {
    Problem problem = Problem.builder()
        .withStatus(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
        .withDetail("Test Message " + ex.getMessage())
        .build();
    return create(ex, problem, request);
}
```

**Console:**

```
Hibernate: update category set created_by = 'abc' where id = 1234
19:37:49.126 [XNIO-1 task-9] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: P0001
19:37:49.127 [XNIO-1 task-9] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: Not allowed to update 
the value of created_by
  Where: PL/pgSQL function noupdate() line 3 at RAISE
.......
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Not allowed to update the value of created_by
Where: PL/pgSQL function noupdate() line 3 at RAISE
```

**Question is**

Currently, `ex.getMessage()` returns *org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement*.

- How can I fetch the message described in the trigger (i.e *PSQLException*:  *Not allowed to update 
  the value of created_by*)
- If I remove the `JpaSystemException`, *handleTriggerException* does not work anymore, why?

*Environment:*

Framework: Spring Boot 
ORM: Hibernate 
Database: Postgres 11

---

UPDATE:

I have tried to get a message with the following methods but unfortunately, they all return the same message.

```
System.out.println("1: " +ex.getCause());
System.out.println("2: " +ex.getMessage());
System.out.println("3: " +ex.getLocalizedMessage());
System.out.println("4: " +ex.fillInStackTrace());
System.out.println("5: " +ex.getStackTrace());

1: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
2: could not execute statement; nested exception is         org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
3: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
4: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement    
5: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6f3072be
```

Comment: `Caused by:` means that you need to call `getCause()` to get the underlying exception.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I have tried with `getCause()` and other methods but unfortunately, they all give the same message *org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement.* I have updated the question accordingly

Comment: If you cast to a JdbcException or   GenericJDBCException you can then extract information like root sqlexception, error code or sql state

Comment: Thanks, @CodeScale, I have solved the issue using `ExceptionUtils `

Comment: Thanks, @Andreas. for your hint. I am able to get the message using `ExceptionUtils` with  `getRootCause(throwable)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [ExceptionUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17747175/10961238) with [getRootCause(throwable)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17747175/10961238) gives the root cause message.

```
@ExceptionHandler({PSQLException.class, GenericJDBCException.class, JpaSystemException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleTriggerException(Exception ex, NativeWebRequest request) {

        Problem problem = Problem.builder()
            .withStatus(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .withDetail(ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(ex).getMessage())
            .build();
        return create(ex, problem, request);
}
```

[How to get root cause message?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17747175/10961238)

Comment: This answer would probably be more useful if you specified what `ExceptionUtils` is.