# How to parse exception message and log ut?

Tags: java, exception

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
               at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
               at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
               at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
               at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:896)
               at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:870)
               at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter.doWrite(JpaItemWriter.java:104)
               at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter.write(JpaItemWriter.java:83)
               at com.kroger.locationloader.batch.extract.InputBufferItemWriter.write(InputBufferItemWriter.java:30)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:188)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.scan(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:594)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.access$900(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:52)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$3.doWithRetry(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:354)
               at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
               at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:217)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.write(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:428)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:212)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
               at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
               at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
               at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
               at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:203)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowStep.doExecute(FlowStep.java:92)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:203)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
               at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
               at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:65)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
               at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
               at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
               at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
               at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
               at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
               at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
               at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
               at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2933)
               at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3524)
               at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
               at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:637)
               at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
               at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
               at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
               at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
               at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
               at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
               at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
               at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaMergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaMergeEventListener.java:56)
               at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
               at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:235)
               at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:173)
               at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
               at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:884)
               ... 39 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'studentAge', table 'branch_channel.dbo.Student'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:256)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1621)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:592)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:522)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2930)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:471)
               at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
               at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
               at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
               at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
               ... 58 more
```

from the above exception I want to get the below line .How can I do that ?
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'studentAge', table 'branch_channel.dbo.Student'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: You may want to call `getCause().getMessage()` on the exception .

Comment: getCause().getMessage() gives only " could not execute statement" which is above the line i wanted.

Comment: Oh, yes, `getCause().getCause().getMessage()`  should give the right part. Also , there are several ways to find the root cause, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747175/how-can-i-loop-through-exception-getcause-to-find-root-cause-with-detail-messa

Comment: what identifies the text of interest?

Comment: getCause().getCause().getMessage().. wow.. gives exactly what I wanted. Thanks @Arnaud