# Grails Don't Know How To Get Exception

Tags: grails

I try to save a duplicate book to my Book domain class for testing.  I have a **try-catch(Exception ex)** to get the error.

```
BookService bookService

try {
   def book = new Book()
   book.id = 'Lord of the Flies'
   bookSerivce.save(book)
   def anotherBook = new Book()
   anotherBook.id = 'Lord of the Flies'
   bookService.save(anotherBook)
} catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.println(ex.getMessage())
}
```

I use **ex.getMessage()**.  I am getting this error message. This one is pretty much useless.

`could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`

On the other hand, I am getting this error message from the command prompt console. This one I can use.  It clearly says that I already have a book called 'Lord of the Flies' in the database.

`2020-11-02 14:46:39.790 ERROR --- [eduler_Worker-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : (conn=665) Duplicate entry 'Lord of the Flies' for key 'PRIMARY'`

I understand I should not use the catch-all Exception.  I will need to use a more specific Exception class.  I already tried catch (SQLException ex) but it did not catch the error.  I also tried some others Exception classes but they didn't catch the error either.

It also looks like book.save() and bookSerive.save(book) throw a different Exception.

Would you show me which Exception class I can use in the catch() function to capture the correct error please?

Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to say for sure because you haven't shown enough context but a guess is that the `rootCase` exception will have what you want.  Interrogate `e.getCause()` and if that is not null, look at its message.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I don't know what rootCase is.  So, I google rootCase.  I get to this page.  I don't understand what they were saying either.  But at the bottom, someone said I needed to do a while-loop on the ex.getCause()  to get to the most inner exception.  Maybe this is waht I need. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747175/how-can-i-loop-through-exception-getcause-to-find-root-cause-with-detail-messa

Comment: If you're simply trying to debug, you can just log the full stack trace using `ex.printStackTrace()` (if you're just printing to system out), the cause will be listed in the stack trace.  If you're trying to programmatically capture it, you could loop over the causes as you suggested until you find the root.

Comment: I am saying that if you catch an exception, call it `e`, then you can invoke `e.getCause()` to retrieve the `Throwable` that was the root cause of the exception that you caught.

Comment: Maybe I ask the wrong question that make this difficult to answer.  Let me edit the question.  I am using the data service to save my book.  I should ask which Exception class I should use to catch the error. I already tried a different Exception.  None of them can catch the error.  I have tried catch (SQLException.ex) but it won't catch the error.

Comment: "I have tried catch (SQLException.ex) but it won't catch the error." - I expect that is because the error thrown is not a `SQLException`.  If you catch `Exception` and then call `ex.getCause()`, the `Throwable` that is returned from that will indicate what exception caused the exception that you caught to be thrown.  If `getCause()` returns `null`, then the exception you caught *is* the root cause (not likely the case in your particular scenario).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question and the comments below it aren't especially clear to me but something to investigate is the root cause of the exception:

```
BookService bookService

try {
   def book = new Book()
   book.id = 'Lord of the Flies'
   bookSerivce.save(book)
   def anotherBook = new Book()
   anotherBook.id = 'Lord of the Flies'
   bookService.save(anotherBook)
} catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.println(ex.getMessage())
   Throwable t = ex.getCause()
   if(t) {
        // interrogate t as the root cause
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a simple question of mine. But I do understand the problem and answer now.  The problem is there are 5 to 6 different exceptions nested inside the generic Exception class.  I should ask myself which one of these 5/6 exceptions is most make sense to me.