# How to handle cause by Exception in a good Java way

Tags: java, exception, socket-timeout-exception

I have some code in try-catch and in that code I am calling web service.On web service I have set timeout.

I have two web service call one taking no time its working fine and another one taking long to respond problem is not that but because of the time out it should throw SocketTimeoutException but its throwing PrivilegedActionException and after a long stack stace its showing cause by SocketTimeoutException.

I have intentionally put service call time very short to get SocketTimeoutException but its giving me PrivilegedActionException as a primary Exception.

I want to catch SocketTimeoutException and I'm not able to catch PrivilegedActionException becuase at the code level its showing PrivilegedActionException has not been thrown by this try catch.

I have written below code for achieve my goal but it's not working

```
try {
  //some code here for service call
}catch(SocketTimeoutException e)
{
  //not able to come here even though cause of the PrivilegedActionException is SocketTimeoutException 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  //directly coming here OF COURSE
}
```

stacktrace:

```
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
```

Comment: try `SocketTimeoutException | PrivilegedActionException` both in first catch block? Read more [Java find the first cause of an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791610/java-find-the-first-cause-of-an-exception)

Comment: Just for other viewers I am using java 1.6.....this is not supported....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can catch `PrivilegedActionException`, and call [getCause](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29) to get `SocketTimeoutException`. Maybe a while loop is needed if `SocketTimeoutException` is not a direct cause.

```
try{

}catch(PrivilegedActionException e){
    Throwable tmp = e;
    while(tmp != null){
        if(tmp instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
            SocketTimeoutException cause = (SocketTimeoutException) tmp;
            //Do what you need to do here.
            break;
        }
        tmp = tmp.getCause();
    }
}
```

Temporary solution:

```
catch(Exception e){
    if(e instanceof PrivilegedActionException){
         //while loop here
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for the answer but pham I have said that my compiler wont allow me to do catch PrivilegedActionException because the code which I have written in try catch its not throwing PrivilegedActionException

Comment: @AbhishekSuthar so just catch the correct exception, and apply the same logic to get the cause :) The basic idea is you need to call `getCause` to get what you want.

Comment: you are saying that put this code in catch of Exception ?

Comment: @AbhishekSuthar that approach should work, just look ugly in code :(

Comment: @AbhishekSuthar added a suggestion how you do it in `catch Exception`

Answer (score 0):

Its better that you define your own Exception class and perform operations which are required.

Just make sure before throwing the exception you release all the resources which you have been using in your program.